# Payum always showing payment/capture form (with credit card)

Tags: sylius, payum, mollie

I am trying to integrate Mollie into a Sylius application that uses Payum. But when I go to payment, instead of redirecting to Mollie (Omnipay) it just shows this CreditCard Form.

I tried debugging it but I cannot find where I am going wrong. I don't know what I am doing wrong here...

[image: Exammple of the form]

Here's the config

```
sylius_payment:
    gateways:
        mollie: Mollie
payum:
    contexts:
        mollie:
            omnipay:
                type: Mollie
                options:
                    apiKey:   test_...
```

Edit:

I updated to 0.14 but now I get this:

Unrecognized option "omnipay" under "payum.payments.mollie"

I was following the example on the site here:

http://payum.org/doc/0.14/PayumBundle/custom_purchase_examples/stripe_via_omnipay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unrecognized option "omnipay" under "payum.payments.mollie"

You have to use `omnipay_direct` factory name.

> I go to payment, instead of redirecting to Mollie (Omnipay) it just shows this CreditCard Form.

Mollie requires a redirect to thier site, is it (Like Paypal Express Checkout does)? If so you have to use `omnipay_offiste` factory.

Comment: Yeah it is offsite, I'll try with the omnipay_offsite config. Can only try this noon, I'll let you know the outcome. Thanks for the super fast response.

Comment: Not yet, I ended up using Mollie API native, because I kept getting errors and deadline is too soon. 
I will give it another shot when time isn't an issue.